# Spring boot starter for camel rabbitmq v 4.x

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, rabbitmq, apache-camel

It seems the new Apache camel LTS 4.0 doesn't provide an up-to-date version for `org.apache.camel.springboot:camel-rabbitmq-starter`

it seems the latest release is `3.21.2` here https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.camel.springboot/camel-rabbitmq-starter/3.21.2
which seems to not work as expected with Spring Boot 3.

Any suggestions/plans on when it will be supported?

Answer (score 0):

As of Apache Camel v 4.x, it seems `org.apache.camel.springboot:camel-rabbitmq-starter` no longer available, and the fallback option is to use `spring-rabbitmq-component` which its spring boot starter exists under `org.apache.camel.springboot:camel-spring-rabbitmq-starter`

source:

https://camel.apache.org/components/3.21.x/rabbitmq-component.html
https://camel.apache.org/components/4.0.x/spring-rabbitmq-component.html

[image]